# Javascript prompt if else statement redirect not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, redirect, prompt

I know it's not safety encrypted but that is ok, it is just a simple password protected page.

I just want the link to the portfolio page to be password protected. My code works 50% but once you click cancel or type the wrong password it still goes into the page that I want protected :(

How can it just stay on index.html page if they put in the incorrect password or just exit out the prompt alert?

```js
function passWord() {
  var s = "";

  while (s != "pinkdrink") {
    s = prompt("please enter your password");
    if (s == "pinkdrink") {
      window.location.href =
        "projectDir/spring2022.html";
    } else {
      alert("Incorrect password.");
      return (window.location.href = "index.html");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item">
  <a href="projectDir/spring2022.html" onClick="passWord()">
    <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-centered-info thumb-info-no-borders border-radius-0">
      <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
        <img src="img/projects/spring2022/spring2022-thumb.jpg" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="" />
        <span class="thumb-info-title">
          <span class="thumb-info-inner">Client</span>
          <span class="thumb-info-type">Role</span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Basically right now my code:

If user clicks link and enters correct password = goes into portfolio page.
If user enters incorrect password = alerts incorrect but still goes into the portfolio page.

I need my code to be:
If user enters incorrect password = stay on current main index page and not go into portfolio page at all.

Comment: Don't update the `href` at all. Also, I know you're doing something simple, but this password check is completely pointless as it is trivially circumvented by anybody looking at the code for the page.

Comment: while loop makes no sense. if or else is going to exit the page so he loop is meaningless.

Comment: it goes to the page because the link goes to the page....

Answer (score 0):

first remove the href from the a href
and do some changes to the script

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
<a  onClick="passWord()">

<span class="thumb-info thumb-info-centered-info thumb-info-no-borders border-radius-0">
<span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
<img src="img/projects/spring2022/spring2022-thumb.jpg" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="" />
<span class="thumb-info-title">
<span class="thumb-info-inner">Client</span>
<span class="thumb-info-type">Role</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>


function passWord() {
    var s = "";
      s = prompt("please enter your password");
      if (s == "pinkdrink") {
        window.location.href ="projectDir/spring2022.html";
      } else {
        alert("Incorrect password.");
       return (window.location.href = "index.html");
     
    }
  }
```